# Got org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException when i try to click on a button in my application

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Got org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException when i try to click on a button in my application. The actions is clicking on button and execution stopped and getting below error:

```
Select dropdown= new  Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/section/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[9]/span/select")));
        dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
        Thread.sleep(5000L);
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/section/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/p[2]/button")).click();
        WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/section/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/p[2]/button"));

        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

And the Error log is:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (337, 11). Other element would receive the click: ...
>     (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.81)

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, instead of absolute xpath you need to use logical xpath. What are your exact steps? Provide relevant HTML DOM.

Comment: I am trying to add a multiple entries in a application. I mentioned whole operation in for loop to test pagination in my application. After one iteration clicking on save button i am getting this error, And regarding Xpath i will change it.

Comment: Hi Dev, It Got resolved by changing absolute Xpath to relative xpath. Thanks mate.

Comment: No need. thanks. Issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because during the script execution the element is not visible, if you scroll down a little, the element might be visible.

So, in short, you need to induce a small script to scroll down.
Use this before your click statement.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```

Let me know if this helps, or in case of any query.
Cheers!!

Comment: Not Resolved still the same issue.. I can able to click on button but error coming after clicking a button.

Comment: Did you try using `element.click()` instead of using the JavaScript click?

Comment: Yes i did and it worked but after some iterations i am facing the same issue again.